# the way to put the current line at the top of terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

In a linux terminal, how to always put the current line at the top of the terminal.

I tried z  but it did not work, as it only works for vim.

Comment: You often want to see some output from your commands (ls, time, date, ping, ...), so it would be really annoying, if the output would always vanish. Nonetheless, it should be doable with some ansi sequences in your prompt.

Comment: You would include the output of `tput cup 0 0` in your prompt, but it will be really messy and, I think, completely unsatisfying.